# Edit the file and replace the Hex value with Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, hex

I have several larger files (400-800MiB) in which I need to convert Hex values to others.
I can do this in some Hex editor, but I would like to do it automatically, in a Bash script.

I know how to check with xxd whether a given value is in a file:

```
FILE='file.vpk'
SEARCH_STRING='MaxRagdollCount'
OLD_HEX_VALUE="$( echo -n "$SEARCH_STRING" | xxd -p )"
HEX_VALUE=($( xxd -p "$FILE" | grep -E -o "${OLD_HEX_VALUE}222022[0-9]{,2}22" ))
echo "$HEX_VALUE"
```

but I can't figure out how to edit it.

I need to replace the value of

> MaxRagdollCount" "any_number"

(4d6178526167646f6c6c436f756e742220223222)

with

> MaxRagdollCount" "9"

(4d6178526167646f6c6c436f756e742220223922).

Comment: What's wrong with `sed -i 's/MaxRagDollCount" "[0-9]"/MaxRagDollCount" "9"/g' file.vpk`?

Comment: What is the format of your input files? Do they contain a mix of binary and plain text content? Is there a consistent line (or record) separator?

Comment: Are you editing a binary? Consider carefully whether this is an [X/Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @oguz ismail
 Corrupts the file.

Comment: @Grobu
This is a binary file, but it's hard for me to tell what it is.

Comment: @PawełSelen Is it binary data, or is it an executable? If it is just binary data, do you know what application produced the files? What application are they used with?

Comment: Grobu
This is not an executable file. A regular data file. File used by the game: "Dark Messiah Might and Magic Single Player". This is a game created on the "Valve Source" engine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "any number" is always a single digit number (i.e. two hexadecimal characters) the following should work:

```
FILE='file.vpk'
SEARCH_STRING='MaxRagdollCount'
SEARCH_STRING_HEX="$(echo -n "$SEARCH_STRING" | xxd -p -c 0)"
#
# Convert binary to ascii:
xxd -p -c 0 $file > ${FILE}.tmp
#
# Replace every occurrence of "SEARCH_STRING_HEX<double quote><space><double quote><character><character><double quote>" with "SEARCH_STRING_HEX<double quote><space><double quote>39<double quote>".
sed -e "s/${SEARCH_STRING_HEX}222022..22/${SEARCH_STRING_HEX}2220223922/g" < ${FILE}.tmp > ${FILE}.tmp2
xxd -r -p ${FILE}.tmp2 > $FILE
rm -f ${FILE}.tmp ${FILE}.tmp2
```

Comment: It seems to work, but when it starts writing the file again:
`xxd -r ${FILE}.tmp2 > $FILE`
the final file grows endlessly to several dozen gigabytes (the original file is over 20 megabytes).
And the MaxRagDollCount value itself does not change.

Comment: Hmm, well, and I'm sure you figured this out, I had 'xdd' instead of 'xxd' (I fixed it above). Also, I should have provided the -c 0 option, so the output would be all one line, otherwise the 'sed' might not match if it happened to fall between line breaks. Finally, looks like I also should have provided the -p option to the xxd -r command, otherwise it doesn't output anything. I updated the script above, let me know if you still have the problem.